# C# Inheritance variable

Tags: c#, inheritance

Excuse me. As the title, I have a question about C# Inheritance.
For code.

```
namespace test{
    class A
    {
        protected int a = 0;
    }

    class B : A
    {
        a = 1; //error
    }
}
```

Why error? Which one I ignore?

Comment: You need to either assign a value to `a` in a method (or constructor) or convert it to a virtual property (e.g., `virtual protected int a => 0;`) so you can override it in the derived class (e.g., `protected override int a => 1;`).

Comment: @41686d6564 stands w. Palestine 
Ok... I learn the program between Python and Java. Didn't see how different C# extends. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `a` outside of any function.
This is not posable
Try this:

```
namespace test{
    class A
    {
        protected int a = 0;
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B()
        {
            a = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... Although most of the information follow it, I can't find the different with my code. Now, I understand. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with fields, the only way to do it is to define `a` as virtual *property*

```
class A
{
    protected virtual int a { set; get; } = 0;
}

class B : A
{
    protected override int a { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, I don't know C# characteristic. Thanks for give me the way I need to study hard. Thank you very much.